# Сгенерировать автоматически случайное число

Tags: html, javascript

В меню на сайт нужно добавить рандомное число, чтобы оно генерировалось автоматически. То есть, при обновлении страницы оно должно меняться. Диапазон от 900 до 1000.

Comment: Не совсем понятно чего Вы хотите.  
Вы хотите просто показать пользователю случайное число, или в каждую ссылку меню добавить случайное число, чтобы браузер не показал кэшированную копию?

Comment: Просто случайное число. Пользователь заходит на сайт и видит это число, предположим в меню или еще где-то. Если он обновит страницу число будет другим. Вроде ничего сложного.
Пробовал писать на php, подключать в html но ничего, к сожалению, не вышло. Пробовал на javascript но число выходил в окошке. Команда вывода alert кажись была

Comment: Вы регистрировались на сайте, чтобы задать этот вопрос, который легко можно нагуглить?

Comment: Первым делол как раз гуглил. Ничего толкового не нашел

Comment: Как можно не найти по словам «javascript random»?

Comment: А за что минусуем то?!

Comment: >А за что минусуем то?!

очевидно, за лень или неумение гуглить

Comment: @DreamChild, Ваш комментарий очень напоминает высказывание администрации бассейна из известного кинофильма:


    Вот научитесь плавать, тогда дадим воду.

Comment: ![alt text](http://i.imgur.com/rBmHAr4.jpg)

Comment: >Вот научитесь плавать, тогда дадим воду

простите великодушно, а какую воду я все-таки не дал начинающему пловцу? Неужели для того, чтобы поискать в гугле информацию по словосочетанию «javascript random» (или даже «javascript случайное число») необходимо обладать хоть какими-то познаниями в плавании..пардон, программировании?

Ну и потом: 

>Как можно не найти по словам «javascript random»?

Comment: @DreamChild у некоторых в гугле одни пони, иноформационный пузырь называется... или "матричный супермаркет" кому как удобнее. стоит не выключить аналитикс...

Comment: @DreamChild, мне почему-то кажется, что основная проблема у ТС в динамическом изменении содержмого страницы при ее обновлении, а не в доступе к информации, что Math.random в JS возвращает случайное число.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.random](http://javascript.ru/Math.random)

```
function getRandomArbitary(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```